# How to refresh a select menu in JQUERY MOBILE

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm creating a web form using JQuery.

I want to copy previous select fields into another select field using a link. i have it changing the DOM, the value of select1.selectedIndex is changed. however it still visually displays the old value. apparently you need to refresh it so it visually updates. I don't understand the syntax of the refresh method i keep reading around. This is how I tried to do it and it doesn't work.

this is the html for the link

```
    <select name="entry.14.single" id="entry_14">      
      <option value="1"></option>      
      <option value="2">2</option>       
      <option value="3">3</option>       
      <option value="4">4</option>       
      <option value="5">5</option></select> 
    <select name="entry.16.single" id="entry_16">      
      <option value=1""></option>      
      <option value="2">2</option>      
      <option value="3">3</option>       
      <option value="4">4</option>       
      <option value="5">5</option></select> 
    <a href="#" onclick="setSelect('entry_16', 'entry_14');return false;">Same as above</a>
```

here is my javascript:

```
    function setSelect(id1, id2){
      var select1 = document.getElementById(id1); 
      var select2 = document.getElementById(id2); 
      select1.selectedIndex = select2.selectedIndex;
      $('#select1').selectmenu('refresh');
    }
```

can someone please tell me why my refresh statement is not working?

p.s. i know there are other threads on the same issue, i have also read the 'documentation.' please dont link me somewhere else. I have read other sources and its not getting me anywhere. Please just show me what to change in order to get the refresh working properly.

EDIT: heres a jsfiddle you can mess around on
http://jsfiddle.net/AFzqt/7/

Comment: *Please just show me what to change in order to get the refresh working properly.* If you're that desperate, please consider providing a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem, so we can experiment with and improve your code more efficiently.

Comment: I believe it was old Ben Franklin that once said a jsFiddle is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Um is there a reason why you have 3 different jQuery libs included?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AFzqt/7/ use this one instead. SORRY for not being perfect, as it was my first time creating a jsfiddle. regardless, it would not effect the solution to this specific problem. as you can see, when you put any value in the first box and click the button, the value is loaded into the 2nd box when you click on it, you can see it is indexed there. but the visual display is not refreshed.  thanks

Comment: as a reminder, im new here, instead of bashing me please work productively with me to figure out this solution. judging and emphasizing your sarcasm isnt productive nor reputable

Comment: your solution definitely works.thank you for the post! on a side note, how do you pass parameters to event handler functions? for example, I would want to sent entry_16 and entry_14 in as a parameter, because this button appears multiple times in my form. it just doenst look like there is anywhere to add these as parameters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Utilize jQuery event handlers!

The function you are looking for is:

```
selectmenu("refresh")
```

In your example, it would look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#changeButton").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#entry_16").val($("#entry_14").val());
        $("#entry_16").selectmenu("refresh");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AFzqt/8/

Comment: When I tried to use '  $("#entry_16").selectmenu("refresh"); ' in a user defined js function ie, outside document.ready(), it is throwing "undefined is not a function" error. Note: Jquery is included, other jquery statements are working. Can any one solve this. Thanks